# How to create a unix script that outputs data inside of an html table?

Tags: html, shell, unix

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "<html><table border=2>"   
echo"<tr><th>Letter </th> <th>Total</th> <th>Start</th> <th> End</th></tr>"
for i  in $(cat "alphaFile");
do t=`grep -c $i /path/to/my/file`;
b=`grep -c ^$i /path/to/my/file`;
e=`grep -c $i$ /path/to/my/file`;
echo"<tr><td> "$i"  </td> <td> "$t" </td>  <td> "$b" </td> <td> "$e" </td></tr>"
done
echo"</table></html>"
```

This outputs the correct data however it's outputting the literal syntax for an HTML table instead of creating a table.

How can I make the HTML be recognized as HTML so that my output will actually be inside of an HTML table?

Comment: When you write this to alpha.html and open it with a browser, what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [`bcat`](https://github.com/rtomayko/bcat). On Ubuntu you can do the following (on mac try homebrew):

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-bcat
```

and doing this:

```
yourScript.sh | bcat
```